# Is there any way to limit VSCode's "UI update frequency" and privilege typing responsiveness instead?

Tags: macos, performance, visual-studio-code

I am a touch typist and I feel like I often have to "fight" with the keyboard to type in VS Code because it is so busy "doing stuff" as I navigate.

(This is somewhat similar to the effect you have on a Google search where the search term completion interferes with my typing).

For example, scroll down one line and you will find the status bar at the bottom updating the line number and the column number.  On the topside, you'll see the breadcrumbs for what file, class and method you are in, if you are in a language supported by one of your plugins or the base language server.  **Yes, that can be useful, but does it have to be updated on each up/down arrow?  Immediately?**

Intellisense is another one of those things.  Type in  `print(` in Python and, wow, you'll be presented immediately with a dropdown of its arguments.  Geez, how could I get by without that?  Most of the time, I have to `esc` to get rid of these dropboxes.

I compared Sublime Text 4 with VScode in moderately big Python file.  Note the results of scrolling *without extensions*.  Just kept the down arrow pressed down and looked how long it took me to get to the bottom.

```
# 55 VSCode sec to scroll 542 lines w 10 extensions enabled - holding arrow down
# 55 VSCode sec ,, with no enabled extensions
# 19 sec with Sublime Text
```

This is unscientific, but I am really starting to eye neovim,  or going to Sublime again.

I tried to put in delays and disable some intellisense but that ended up disabling snippets too, which is complete no-no.  Disabling Pylance didn't help all that much.  And speaking of snippets, sometimes I type in the snippet trigger and VSCode is busy and tab doesn't do anything till I wait for 2-3 seconds.

Am I missing something in the way I configure vscode?  Should I delete some cache directory somewhere that is stale/disorganized?  I have a 2019 MBP with 16GB RAM, hardly a slouch.  I realize vscode isn't the top choice for performance, but 55sec to scroll down 500 lines vs 19 in Sublime???

Is there a way to say something like "refresh the UI's Chrome every 250msec?"  Web developers use JS libraries to unbounce and ignore immediately succeeding keystrokes so that they don't set Ajax requests on every keystroke.

Can't completely be the Electron backend, my typing is much more free on Vivaldi in the browser, for example.  Also, the macos WindowServer process - which AFAIK deals with screen composition - tends to eat up CPU whenever VS Code is being used, much more so than browsers.

p.s. "UI update frequency" is a rather unclear term here.  Any suggestions welcome.

p.p.s. This is my primary, even only, performance issue with VSCode.  No real problems with startup time, large file opening, etc...  Just slugglish typing.  I *like* VScode!

---

Big apologies.  I should have mentioned I was on macos.  I didn't ask on Ask Different because I did not see VS Code as that app-specific.  No worries with the answers referring to Windows utilities - I've used Windows and have a general sense of how those compare.

Comment: I never tried opening VS with it, but in CheatEngine there's a feature of slowing down ( or speeding up ) the selected process. I don't know how the rest of the UI ( like, typing ) will behave, though. You can disable it while compiling etc. Should look like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEDPgrz1Gl8

Answer (score 2):

There's really no way of doing this that I know of. If you want performance, you could probably change the console scrollback and all that stuff, but the change is going to be small. Killing all unneeded processes will likely have the largest effect. You can mass kill processes with these commands (make sure cmd is open in administrator mode):

**tasklist** (so you can see the processes you don't need, or you could just use task manager, whatever suits you)

**taskkill /im** {insert process name here. You can use wildcard here, eg: a* would kill anything starting with a, and {wildcard}a{wildcard} (it made it italic if I had both surrounding the letter) would kill anything with a in it, and I think you get the idea about *a by now.} **/F** (forces it to be killed)

Comment: The definition of "straightforward"! Can you tell (or point towards) a kinda "Rosetta Stone" specifically for these absolute savages of basic commands? Preferably spanning the major OS/Kernel cross-platform aka NT/ReactOS, Linux/Android, XNU/Darwin, Solaris/Illumos and so on ... Basically asking if there is an equivalence-on-other-os/kernel-table. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can change some **Visual Studio Code** settings on the fly programmatically by updating the [`settings.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) file with PowerShell for example which I will provide an example for you here.

Since you've added the macOS tag to your original question, I wanted to provide you with Microsoft's guide on [Installing PowerShell on macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-macos?view=powershell-7.3) since I provided a PowerShell solution.

### Step 1

- Make a backup copy of `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json` and store it somewhere secure. You'll use this to replace the modified file for quick reversion should there be issues just in case.

### Step 2

- Consider reading over the [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) post to stay updated with the latest and for a better and more thorough assessment and understanding.

**Key points** to consider per [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) post as it relates to this answer and toggling VSCode settings:

- > Some settings can only be edited in `settings.json` such as **Workbench:
  > Color Customizations** and show an **Edit in settings.json** link in the
  > Settings editor.
- > [**Settings file locations**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations)
  >
  > Depending on your platform, **the user settings file** is located here:
  >
  > - **Windows:** `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
  > - **macOS:** `$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json`
  > - **Linux:** `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`
- > [**Reset all settings**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_reset-all-settings)
  >
  > While you can reset settings individually via the Settings editor
  > **Reset Setting** command, you can reset all changed settings by opening `settings.json` and deleting the entries between the braces
  > `{}`. Be careful since there will be no way to recover your previous
  > setting value
- > [**Workspace
  > settings**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_workspace-settings)
  >
  > Workspace settings are specific to a project and can be shared across
  > developers on a project. Workspace settings override user settings.
  >
  > > **Note:** A VS Code "workspace" is usually just your project root folder.
  > > Workspace settings as well as [debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) and
  > > [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) configurations
  > > are
  > > stored at the root in a `.vscode` folder. You can also have more than
  > > one root folder in a VS Code workspace through a feature called
  > > [Multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces).
- > [**Workspace `settings.json`
  > location**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_workspace-settingsjson-location)
  >
  > Similar to User Settings, Workspace Settings are also stored in a
  > `settings.json` file, which you can edit directly via the
  > **Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)** command.
  >
  > The workspace settings file is located under the `.vscode` folder in
  > your root folder.
  >
  > The File Explorer displaying settings.json under the .vscode folder
  >
  > > **Note:** For a [Multi-root Workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_settings),
  > > workspace settings are located inside the workspace configuration
  > > file.
  >
  > When you add a Workspace Settings `settings.json` file to your project
  > or source control, the settings for the project will be shared by all
  > users of that project.

### PowerShell

**Note:** *This is just a small example of some of the options, you'll have to figure out the specific and other options which are applicable at the user settings level that you want toggled.*

```
## VSCode user settings settings.json
$filePath = "$env:APPDATA\Code\User\settings.json";

## Create a backup of the settings.json
$backupPath = "$env:APPDATA\Code\User\settings_backup.json";
Copy-Item -Path $filePath -Destination $backupPath -Force;

## Convert the JSON data to a PowerShell object
$json = Get-Content -Raw $filePath | ConvertFrom-Json;

## Add the new properties
$json | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "editor.wordWrap" -Value "off" -Force
$json | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "editor.minimap.enabled" -Value $false -Force
$json | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "editor.suggestSelection" -Value "first" -Force
$json | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "editor.tabCompletion" -Value "off" -Force
$json | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "editor.renderLineHighlight" -Value "none" -Force
$json | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "editor.scrollbar.horizontal" -Value "hidden" -Force
$json | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "editor.scrollbar.vertical" -Value "hidden" -Force
$json | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "editor.scrollBeyondLastLine" -Value $false -Force
$json | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "editor.renderControlCharacters" -Value $false -Force

## Convert back to JSON to the file
$json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $filePath;
```

### PowerShell (Revert - remove explicit properties)

**Note:** *This reversion shows property setting removals explicitly from the JSON. Another trivial but simple solution though would be the copy the backup of the JSON settings file back to it's original name using `-Force`.*

```
## VSCode user settings settings.json
$filePath = "$env:APPDATA\Code\User\settings.json";

## Create a backup of the settings.json
$backupPath = "$env:APPDATA\Code\User\settings_backup.json";
Copy-Item -Path $filePath -Destination $backupPath -Force;

## Convert the JSON data to a PowerShell object:
$json = Get-Content -Raw $filePath | ConvertFrom-Json;

## Remove properties
$json.PSObject.Properties.Remove('editor.wordWrap');
$json.PSObject.Properties.Remove('editor.minimap.enabled');
$json.PSObject.Properties.Remove('editor.suggestSelection');
$json.PSObject.Properties.Remove('editor.tabCompletion');
$json.PSObject.Properties.Remove('editor.renderLineHighlight');
$json.PSObject.Properties.Remove('editor.scrollbar.horizontal');
$json.PSObject.Properties.Remove('editor.scrollbar.vertical');
$json.PSObject.Properties.Remove('editor.scrollBeyondLastLine');
$json.PSObject.Properties.Remove('editor.renderControlCharacters');

## Convert back to JSON to the file
$json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $filePath;
```

### PowerShell (Revert - restore settings.json from backup )

**Note:** *This reversion will use the backup file of settings.json and restore it.*

```
## VSCode user settings settings.json
$filePath = "$env:APPDATA\Code\User\settings.json";

## Create a backup of the settings.json
$backupPath = "$env:APPDATA\Code\User\settings_backup.json";
Copy-Item -Path $backupPath -Destination $filePath -Force;
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Add new key value pair to JSON file in powershell.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724114/add-new-key-value-pair-to-json-file-in-powershell)
- [Remove a Member from a PowerShell Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905060/remove-a-member-from-a-powershell-object)

Comment: @JLPeyret .... I tested this with some settings and confirmed it works. This is the closest way to do this, but it'll take a little scripting and digging to find the applicable settings you want to toggle, but I picked these as a small sample set. There are so many options though, that's the hard part to pick apart. The rest is just trivial but I'm happy to extend on this answer further if you tell me to, etc. Good luck!!

Comment: I'll accept this because it is more comprehensive, but to be honest I am almost more inclined to believe the brutal honesty of Jax's answer - can't be done as such.  That said, I'll if I can leverage some of your ideas to learn how to better control VS Code.  Re. backups, a `git init ; git add settings.json` is what I use.

Comment: Also, one nice thing with a programmatic approach - which I will do via Python rather than PS - is that I can avoid my problem of randomly tweaking settings in the UI, then noting that say snippet tab completion is gone and reverting the whole file back.

Comment: It seems to work for me for on the fly disabling some of the settings I tested at least dynamically like that without even closing the app. It was a fun cool little project regardless, so I appreciate the question and your bounty!

Comment: Did you already work out that Python logic? Can you send me a pastebin link to check it out if you're willing to share? Just curious to see what it looks like, I've done a little Python but nothing extensive like I do with PowerShell everyday of my life, Lol @JLPeyret

Comment: No, I just re-read once again the details of what you posted when deciding who to give the bounty to.  So nowhere near figuring a Python script to do so.  Shouldn't be hard a such, but ideally I would *also* keep track of settings *and their effect* in a spreadsheet/markdown document so that I am more disciplined.  Lots of settings in VS Code and I've tried some of them in the past, before this slowdown.  Unless there is a *very* clear relationship between name/description and an effect (say snippet completion disappearance) it is easy to lose track when you flipped 5 or 6 booleans manually.

Answer (score 1):

I feel sheepish for posting this "solution", but I found that VS Code behaved considerably better after I rebooted my machine.

One doesn't expect, in 2023, that rebooting a modern OS would somehow fix a slowdown *that affected VS Code and only VS Code*.  Might expect that out of something lower level or a persistent system error, not a user level application slowdown.

But it did.

I still think VS Code would benefit from having the ability to privilege typing over feedback-oriented UI updates.  Especially if a machine has a busy CPU compiling or the like.

Answer (score 0):

The bug-report
[Slow reponse to scroll and typing #107016](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107016)
is about this very problem.

There are no solutions for the problem, just workarounds, since a real
solution must come from the VScode team.

Most workarounds seem to indicate that VScode is very inefficient on using
the GPU.

The following switches were reported as improving the performance:

- `--disable-gpu`
- `--disable-gpu-compositing`

For NVIDIA, one user solved the problem in the NVIDIA Control Panel by
creating an NVIDIA profile for `code.exe` which has in it only
the one setting `0x10B135FE` with the value of `0x00000000`.
This setting is said to remove the default framerate limit
from VScode.
With this profile, the issue was solved on his computer.